# How to connect multiwebsites to multi domain in godaddy hosting in magento2.2.4?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.4

I have created multi website in admin panel and I tried to access this website from the browser.

I am getting 403 forbidden error.

Comment: Did you point the domains to the your current server? If yes then update the url in your database core_config_data table.

Comment: Sure. If you want me to answer then comment.

Comment: please check my updated question